# How To Change Color of Certain Words Inside a Label?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I wanted to change the color of certain words inside the Label. I saw similar example of using color change of words in text widget with `tag_configure` and `tag_add` but it didnt work, the color doesn't display. Not sure what is the mistake in the below code?

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.top_left_label = Label(parent, text="Top Left")
        self.top_left_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=N+S+W)

        self.top_right_label = Label(parent, text="Top Right")
        self.top_right_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=N+S+E)

        mytext = Text(root)
        mytext.insert(INSERT, "Enter the Apple %d Configuration Name"% 2)
        mytext.tag_configure("highlight", background="red")
        mytext.tag_add("highlight", "11.0", "16.0")
        self.ad_l0 = Label(root, text=mytext.get("1.0", END))

        self.ad_l0.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W')
        self.ad_l0.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)


root = Tk()
root.title("Test UI")
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php

Answer (score 0):

First you should `grid()` the Text directly, without inserting it in a new Label, because this will reset all tags in the label (`mytext.get("1.0", END)` will only copy the text, not the tags).

Then the indexes for the selection is looking for the lines 11 to 16. Please refer to this [doc](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#modifying), it explains the different selectors you can use.

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.top_left_label = Label(parent, text="Top Left")
        self.top_left_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=N+S+W)

        self.top_right_label = Label(parent, text="Top Right")
        self.top_right_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=N+S+E)

        self.mytext = Text(root)
        self.mytext.insert(INSERT, "Enter the Apple %d Configuration Name"% 2)

        self.mytext.tag_add("highlight", "1.0", "2.0") # colors the whole 1st line
        #self.mytext.tag_add("highlight", "1.10", "1.15") # colors only 'Apple' 
        self.mytext.tag_configure("highlight", background="red")
        self.mytext.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W')
```

Comment: THanks for the clarification. But is it not at-all possible to explicitely change the color of particular words in the Label itself ? Rather than grid-ding the text?

Comment: Nope at all: `'Label' object has no attribute 'tag_add'`

Comment: _"First you should grid()"_ - why? Both `grid` and `pack` have strengths and weaknesses, and neither have anything to do with changing colors or resetting tags in a text widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley `grid` or `pack` doesn't matter here, i agree, i was mostly speaking about adding the `Text` to the layout, not the `Label` (and `grid` is already used in the code..)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use more than two colors (foreground and background) with a label. If you need multiple colors you will have to use a small canvas or text widget.